# Python escape '$' character in variable name

Tags: python, swagger, bravado

I'm using bravado, which has created functions for me to call based on a swagger definition. The swagger definition contains query parameters prefixed with `$`. I.e. `client.pet.get_pets($limit=10)`.

Problem is, I can't use `$limit=10` because it throws a syntax error.

Is there a way to escape this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python variable names and Python keyword argument names (which is what you actually need her) cannot contain `$`.  You may be able to use the `**kwargs` syntax though:

```
client.pet.get_pets(**{"$limit": 10})
```